# sql query error while using joins with where an in operators

Tags: mysql, sql

These are my tables

[image]

[image]

I am trying to write a query where i can give a date to search weather the date between start and end dates in events table or specific_date in specific dates table and retrieve records from events

**eg :**

```
select * from events left join specificdates on events.event_id=specificdates.event_id WHERE ('2017-01-29' BETWEEN events.start_date AND events.end_date) OR  ('2017-01-29' IN 
    specificdates.spefific_date)
```

Comment: show us your tried query

Comment: i just added  the query

Comment: @goutam can suggest the query

Comment: is it my questions work ?

Comment: yes thanks for the query  krishn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
 select * from events left join specificdates on events.event_id=specificdates.event_id
 WHERE ('2017-01-29' BETWEEN 
 events.start_date AND events.end_date) OR  (specificdates.spefific_date IN ('2017-01-29'))
```